# How to transfer php data to html file?

Tags: php, html

After I login the user, I want to have a separate html page (a front page) that says "welcome, (user)." I tried to use cookies and I now know this wont work. So how would i go about doing this?

Here is my code (in my sigin script):

```
header('Location: frontpage.html');
```

In frontpage.html, I want to use some of the data from the sigin script.

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the $_SESSION array. When your user logs in, you should set some $_SESSION variables to whatever values you want (say, one variable which will let you know the user is logged in, another with their user name, another with their permissions, etc.).

Then just echo the $_SESSION variable with the relevant user name to the user:

```
echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '.';
```

The PHP manual has extensive information on sessions:
http://il2.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Answer (score 1):

I would def not use cookies to save user credentials as this can be ripped from your browser with an inject script or harmful site.  Look into [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to achieve user log ins.

In terms of serving html to a client browser that is very easy.  You could load the html page with PHP and echo it to the browser.  Since PHP is a server side language this script output is produced before being sent to the client.  The html would be rendered into the browsers DOM and you are done.

But I would suggest using an MVC framework like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or I have created a very simple un-bloated MVC called [PHPBlueprint](http://phpblueprint.com/) that would work (and be very easy to configure).  This will allow you flexibility and abstractions between your coding logic.

**UPDATE**

This would be myPage.php

```
<?php

    $myVar = 3;

    echo "<html>
          <head>
              <title>My Page</title>
          </head>
          <body>
              $myVar
          </body>
          </html>";
?>
```

or you could do:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $myVar = 3;
        echo $myVar;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Either way you choose to do this the script will be run on the server and then send the data to a client browser as:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   3
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML will be rendered into the DOM and the page should look display:

```
3
```

PHP is very much worth the time to learn, as is MVC as it promotes great OOP and expandable solutions for rapid development.  Look at [PHPBlueprint](http://phpblueprint.com/) as this will simplify all of these and will be easy to reverse engineer.

Comment: So there is no way to use any PHP data variables in html??

Comment: Your php runs on the server side - the login and everything.  This is then sent to the client after it has run.  So yes, you use variables.  I'll show an example in my post.

Comment: Use templating engine (such as Smarty) - you can embed variables from your PHP inside your template, which is what you seem to need exactly. Or use echo - there is no other way.

Comment: Yup, using a template engine will also work, and further more can be embedded into an MVC framework to add more modularity.

Answer (score 0):

use php echo inside your code
http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

but if you want this to work as you say, use templating engine. I suggest [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

Comment: I do not want to use echo because in the future, I need to link things to other pages

Comment: I think you lack the overall understanding of what server script (in this case php does). I am also not clear what you are actually asking. Are you asking how to output characters to the web page? Or are you asking how to grab the logged in user? If it's the former, use echo or templating engine. If it's the latter, see the answer above mine - login is stored in the SESSION regardless of the scripting language you are using.